Dual function breakers tripping, lights flickering, and temporary power loss, all on one leg
I've been having electrical issues for several years that have gotten worse in the last year.  Three different electricians and the power company have taken a look and have not been able to solve them, so I'm hoping someone can help give me a lead.  Thank you in advance!
Issues (which may or may not be related):

Nuisance Tripping:  7 different breakers are frequently tripping (25 trips in the past month).  Sometimes it's a single breaker tripping; sometimes it's multiple breakers tripping (we've seen up to 6 trip at once).  They are all on the same leg (every other row).  They are all Square D dual function breakers.  None of the 3 standard single-pole breakers and 3 CAFCI-only breakers on the same leg have tripped.  None of the 12 single-pole breakers on the other leg have tripped (and several of them are the same model of dual function breaker that is tripping on the other leg).  No dual-pole breakers on either leg has tripped.

Flickering Lights:  Lights in our primary bedroom and in the kitchen flicker frequently (multiple times per day).  Sometimes, we notice that this corresponds to new load on the system (A/C starting, furnace fan starting, dehumidifier starting), but sometimes we do not notice any new load.  These circuits are also on the same leg as the breakers that we experience nuisance tripping on.  We have not noticed flickering lights for circuits on the other leg, but we also tend to not spend as much time in those rooms (so perhaps it's happening, and we just haven't noticed).

Momentary Power Loss:  This is fairly infrequent but has happened at least twice in the past month.  We've noticed that there appears to be momentary power loss on two of our circuits based on clocks being reset or TVs powering on from a cold boot state rather than from standby.  Both circuits are on the same leg as the nuisance tripping and flickering lights.  I've been present right as this happened once, and the power loss was for about 30 seconds for that particular instance.


Troubleshooting that we've performed:

An electrician noticed some sizzling when flipping a light switch.  They said this was caused by backstabbing and suggested we redo all receptacles (over 100!).  We had them redo all light switches on one of our circuits as a test, but that did not fix the flickering lights or nuisance tripping on that circuit.

Another electrician claimed that they have never been successful fixing this problem by redoing backstabbed receptacles.  They instead suggested replacing the breakers with a different brand (Eaton).  We have not tried this yet.

Multiple electricians verified that all the connections in our breaker box were secure and that the wiring looked correct.

The power company looked at remote logs and saw no issues.

The power company came out and performed a physical inspection of our meter under load.  Voltage was stable under load.

I used a plug-in outlet tester on all receptacles for a few circuits (but not all).  So far, no problems have been detected with the wiring.

I've read online that multiple dual function breakers tripping might be caused by shared neutrals.  This seems unlikely in my case, however, given that I have 7 different breakers tripping.


Other potentially relevant info:

The house is less than 10 years old.

200A service.

We noticed the occasional nuisance trip early on.  However, it initially happened just a couple times per year, so we ignored it.  In the past 1-2 years, the frequency has increased.  We typically see several episodes per week.


The momentary power loss (which is relatively new) makes me think there may be a loose connection somewhere, so I'm planning to examine some of the receptacles next.  But, I'm not sure if this could explain the nuisance tripping and flickering lights, especially since these are happening on multiple circuits.
Any theories on what might be causing all these issues, and any suggestions on what to do next?
Thanks again!

LEDs are very good for showing problems in the electrical system.  I would change one breaker(one with the most trippings) to try to limit the area of the problem.  The problem does sound like a loose connection on the power line side.  If power line is above ground from the pole, does the problems seem to be worst with a wind blowing?

Important:   "getting worse"  <-- this means something is gradually failing/fading and it is unlikely to improve.   I'd be tempted to present the electrician with "it's a challenge" and see them send out either their smartest young one or the old grizzled one who has seen it all.  In either case that will be someone who can think laterally, and not a box-ticker kind of person with a quota to complete.

Thank you both.  Both of your hunches were correct.  The problem turned out to be a melted wire on the utility pole for just the single leg of power that had been giving us issues.  The power technician who repaired it thought it could have been damaged for years, gradually failing more and more.  I actually did notice that the problem occurred more frequently when it was rainy/windy too, but I ended up not mentioning it my post because it wasn't 100% correlated.  Thank you for the help!

Have an electrician check the wires from the meter to the circuit breaker panel.
That the problem happens on every other row of the circuit breakers, which you've diagnosed correctly as one leg of the power, and that they're dual-function breakers (which means they include AFCI protection) strongly indicates to me that one of the main power wires into your home has a hairline break or poor connection in it.

The power company looked at remote logs and saw no issues.
The power company came out and performed a physical inspection of our meter under load. Voltage was stable under load.

Theoretically this means that the power wires from the power company's transformer to the meter are OK. This does not mean that the power wires from the meter to the panel with the tripping breakers is OK.
Also, power companies can mis-diagnose. We had a lost neutral at our house, and the power company thought it was in their overhead wire. Turned out it was in our meter-to-panel cable.
A utility cable or power-to-meter cable issue can trigger AFCI breakers. The AFCI portion cannot determine whether the noise of loose connections it listens for is coming from past the breaker inside the house, or behind the breaker in the main power wires. So they can trip on loose connections in the power leg.
The momentary power loss on a couple circuits can also fit in with the bad power leg wire.
Note, this could still be the case if you have one of those combination meter and circuit breaker panels, where the connection from the meter to the breaker bus bars is built-in. Perhaps there is a manufacturing defect.

Thank you for the help!  Serendiptously, the day after I posted this, we had 8 breakers trip, power go in and out, and finally, power go out completely in just the problematic leg of power.  The power company came out, and their technician said that one of the wires on the utility pole had completely melted.  He said it could have been damaged for years, explaining our problem.  Your troubleshooting was spot on: it was upstream of the main breaker, and the power company's previously mis-diagnosed it (not faulting them, as repro wasn't constant).  Thanks again!

I'm glad you got it fixed! Here's something to research for the future: "lost neutral". It's a similar problem to what your home had, except the neutral wire goes bad instead of one of the legs. The voltage between the legs and neutral then varies depending on the loads you have on, and damage to 120V devices can happen. Often spotted by seeing the lights dim and brighten as large 120V loads turn on and off.

Sounds like a poor neutral connection to me. Most likely it is the neutral connection in your main panel. It should be uninterrupted from your service entry to your main panel.

This is actually a good possibility. A poor neutral will affect both legs, causing flickering on leg A if high loads come on and off on leg B, etc, swinging the voltages like a see-saw. If OP's diagnosis has missed something, or all of their 120V high-current loads happen to be on one leg, the effect could seem to be all on the other leg. Only question is, would the AFCI's "hear" the bad connection noise on the main neutral? The AFCIs are tripping on something. (Op has AFCI on both legs.)

Thank you for the idea!  It turned out to be a melted wire on the utility pole for just the leg of power that had been giving us issues.  If we hadn't gotten lucky and had the wire finally melt all the way through, I think we would have looked at the poor neutral theory too.
